# How to update a progress bar in a loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

What is the easy method to update Tkinter progress bar in a loop?

I need a solution without much mess, so I can easily implement it in my script, since it's already pretty complicated for me.

Let's say the code is:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk


root = Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(400, 100))
theLabel = Label(root, text="Sample text to show")
theLabel.pack()


status = Label(root, text="Status bar:", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

root.mainloop()

def loop_function():
    k = 1
    while k<30:
    ### some work to be done
    k = k + 1
    ### here should be progress bar update on the end of the loop
    ###   "Progress: current value of k =" + str(k)


# Begining of a program
loop_function()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a quick example of continuously updating a `ttk` progressbar. You probably don't want to put `sleep` in a GUI. This is just to slow the updating down so you can see it change.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import time

MAX = 30

root = Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(400, 100))
progress_var = DoubleVar() #here you have ints but when calc. %'s usually floats
theLabel = Label(root, text="Sample text to show")
theLabel.pack()
progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, variable=progress_var, maximum=MAX)
progressbar.pack(fill=X, expand=1)


def loop_function():

    k = 0
    while k <= MAX:
    ### some work to be done
        progress_var.set(k)
        k += 1
        time.sleep(0.02)
        root.update_idletasks()
    root.after(100, loop_function)

loop_function()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using `root.update_idletasks()` makes the windows unresponsive.

But `root.update()` doesn't make the window unresponsive.

Comment: @skarfa: No, calling `time.sleep()` in a tkinter gui program is what makes this unresponsive (because it temporarily suspends the gui's `mainloop`). The OP alludes to this in their description.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what I figured out:**

First define a function to update the variable  `self.prog_precent = tk.DoubleVar()` using `set()`.

```
def prog_bar_update(self, value):

    self.prog_precent.set(value)
```

Then, update the root `tk` followed by calling `self.after()` in every 10 ms in the main loop, e.g.:

```
 count = 0
 for _ in range(100):

    do something ...
    count += 1 
    time.sleep(1)
    self.update()

    self.after(10, self.prog_bar_update, count)
```

Here is important to note that `self` might be different. In my case, it is the parent root - `tk`.

Finally run your main application:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    gs_gui = MainWindow(None)   # here is `MainWindow(tk.Tk):`
    gs_gui.mainloop()
```