# How can I fix value of progress bar in tkinter (it just ends in middle)

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

I have a problem with updating a value into progress bar and when I run my program, the progress bar stuck in middle (just click 'Problem Here' button below, it explain what I mean) , the code was run successfully without any error

here's code that I used :

```
self.bytes = 0
self.max_bytes = 0

self.progressbarframe = Frame(self.frameoutput, bg=self.bgcolor)
self.progressbarframe.place(relx=0.355,rely=0.78,relwidth=0.605)

self.progressbar = Progressbar(self.progressbarframe, orient=HORIZONTAL, mode='determinate')
self.progressbar.pack(fill=X)

def progress(curvalue, maxval):
    self.progressbar['value'] = curvalue
    self.progressbar['maximum'] = maxval

def cb(total, recvd, ratio, rate, eta):
    self.bytes += recvd
    self.max_bytes += total
    if self.bytes <= self.max_bytes:
        self.progressbar.after(50, progress(self.bytes, self.max_bytes))
        self.progressbar.update()

self.videos = pafy.new(str(self.entryyturl.get()))
self.videodownload = self.videos.allstreams
self.videodownload = self.videodownload[-int(self.data['mediatypes'].index(self.resolutionbox.get()))-1]
self.videodownload.download(quiet=True, filepath='download/{}.{}'.format(self.videodownload.title, self.videodownload.extension), callback=cb)
```

[Problem Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V9x7.jpg)

Thank You!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update a progress bar in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36516497/how-to-update-a-progress-bar-in-a-loop)

Comment: Without looking too closely at your code, try changing this: `self.progressbar.after(50, progress(self.bytes, self.max_bytes))` to this: `self.progressbar.after(50, lambda: progress(self.bytes, self.max_bytes))`

Comment: Add `print(curvalue, maxval)` to see what you get.